# How to install the proprietary driver "wl" after removing the broadcom-sta package from Kali repository?

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, broadcom

I'm trying to configure a MacBook Pro Wireless Adapter in Kali Linux but all of the tutorials I've found suggest installing the `broadcom-sta-dkms package`, however [as of yesterday it has been removed form the Kali rolling repository](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/broadcom-sta). I've tried downloading the `.deb` and unpacking it locally but I get the following error:

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.14.0-kali3-amd64 (x86_64)
```

Is there another way to configure the BCM4360 wireless card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `broadcom-sta` is removed from Kali repository on 2018-01-30 as the package information say . A temporary solution is to get the package from debian Sid repository until a new package which provide the `wl` driver will be available from kali repository.

```
apt update && apt dist-upgrade
apt install gdebi linux-headers-4.14.0-kali3-amd64
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/b/broadcom-sta/broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-7_all.deb
gdebi broadcom-sta/broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-7_all.deb
modprobe wl
```

**Update : the above answer is deprecated**

The package `broadcom-sta` is available again in kali repository ( [imported on 2018-02-24](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/broadcom-sta)).

System update:

```
apt update 
apt upgrade
reboot
```

Package install:

```
apt install broadcom-sta
modprobe wl
```

[Debian docs: wl](https://wiki.debian.org/wl)